# Postgres-Netbeans

Tags: postgresql, netbeans

Hola hace unos días formule una pregunta en la cual pedía ayuda  para saber como podría generar la conexión entre postgres y netbeans ....
En una de sus respuestas  me recomendaron tutorialspoint....
cabe mencionar que la aplicación que estoy haciendo como proyecto escolar es un punto de venta para una óptica en la cual tengo que guardar en un expediente  los datos delos pacientes.

Para generar la conexión utilice este código...

```
import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;



public class PostgreSQLJDBC {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Connection c = null;

        try{
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            c = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres","postgres","12345");

        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName()+": "+e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("ACCESO TOTAL A LA BASE DE DATOS");
        }
    }
```

Para esto la cree en una clase en java ...... 
ahora me podrían decir   si esta conexión es la ideal para el tipo de aplicación que estoy creando?
y que tendría que poner en el botón guardar para llamar a la b.d  y se guarden los archivos ?
Muchas gracias & disculpen la verdad es que aun tengo muchas dudas entorno a la programación y a entender el código.....
Lamentablemente creo que aprendo mas  buscando en Internet que con mis maestros..

Comment: En mi respuesta a tu pregunta anterior expliqué cuál es la mejor manera.